# Making an image grayscale on Firefox

Tags: html, css, image, firefox

I am stuck at a place where my HTML and CSS works on Chrome and IE but not Firefox. I have applied grayscale through CSS.

```
<div class="content_text"> 
    <img class="grpimg" src="../clients/2AEW%20Infratech.JPG" />
    <img class="grpimg" src="../clients/4APCTT.JPG" />
    <img class="grpimg" src="../clients/astonfield.PNG"/>
</div>
```

```
.content_text .grpimg{
    width:30%;
    height:30%;
    margin:7px;
    filter: grayscale(100%); /* Current draft standard */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* New WebKit */

    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%); 
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Not yet supported in Gecko, Opera or IE */ 
    filter: url(resources.svg#desaturate); /* Gecko */
    filter: gray; /* IE */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Old WebKit */
}
```

Comment: So the whole image is not visible? Or only the grayscale? And if you remove the grayscale, do they appear then?

Comment: Tangentially, you might want to consider removing the `grpimg` class altogether if it applies to *all* the images in the `.content_text` div. Just use `.content_text img`

Comment: What if you move `filter: grayscale(100%);` under all other `filter` directives?

Comment: Are we expected to guess what's in `resources.svg`? The offending line is clearly `filter: url(resources.svg#desaturate); /* Gecko */`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this

```
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
```

instead of

```
filter: url(resources.svg#desaturate)
```

Comment: Like this: http://www.karlhorky.com/2012/06/cross-browser-image-grayscale-with-css.html

Comment: Thx kirelagin...:)
filter: url(resources.svg#desaturate)
was making it to disappear..., Now its working

Comment: Is it me or the result is blurry?

Answer (score 0):

From Firefox 35 `filter: grayscale(100%);` should work too.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility